# Can Dr Watson be run so that it is not in the taskbar?

Tags: debugging, windows-xp, taskbar, crash-dumps, drwatson

Can `Dr Watson` be run so that it is not in the taskbar?

If not, how else can you automatically generate crash dumps without something being in the taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).